# Email: Remote host address is the local host

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, exim

I try to send an e-mail to my Ubuntu server. After waiting a long wail, nothing happens. This is what I found in my log files:

```
2011-04-22 15:23:01 1QDGK5-0003BI-On remote host address is the local host: ***.net
2011-04-22 15:23:01 1QDGK5-0003BI-On == postmaster@***.net R=dnslookup_relay_to_domains defer (-1): remote host address is the local host
2011-04-22 15:23:01 1QDGK5-0003BI-On Frozen
```

When I try again, I still get this error. What can I do about it? I'm using Exim4 on Ubuntu (and DBMail).

Answer (score 4):

Well, exim thinks that `***.net` is a remote host and failed when trying to forward the mail because you have not added `***.net` to local_domains like this: `domainlist local_domains = @ : localhost : ***.net`

Answer (score 1):

It may have to do with your `/etc/hosts` file. If you have set the domain, you want to send to, to localhost.